# PrimeFaces tags not rendered

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to make my first page using PrimeFaces Mobile, but the tags are not rendered.

My xhtml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
<f:view>
    <f:loadBundle basename="test.Labels"
        var="labels" />
    <h:head>
        <title>#{labels.PageTitle}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <pm:page title="Hello World">
            <pm:view id="main">
                <pm:header title="Header" />

                <pm:content>Content</pm:content>
                <pm:buttonGroup orientation="horizontal">
                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" />
                    <p:commandButton value="No" />
                </pm:buttonGroup>
            </pm:view>
        </pm:page>

    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

I am using:

- jsf 2.0
- embedded jetty
- primefaces-3.3.jar
- primefaces-mobile-0.9.3.jar

I have tried to add also:

```
<application>
   <default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</default-render-kit-id> 
</application>
```

But an exception occurred:
Could not find a RenderKit for "PRIMEFACES_MOBILE".
Without this, the PrimeFaces tags are not rendered.

Thanks and any help is strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now solved.

The PrimeFaces jar (primefaces-3.3.jar in my case) has to be available in the folder /WEB-INF/lib at runtime

My big mistake.